# JPQL count for an arbitrary dynamic query

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I'm executing an arbitrary JPQL query and I need to be able to count the total results for pagination.

Example Code for the execution of the query:

`public List<?> executeQuery (String jpqlQuery) {
    List<?> results = null;
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery (jpqlQuery);
    try {
        results = query.getResultList();
    } catch PersistenceException|DatabaseException pe) {
        // log error
    }
    return results;
}`

Note: I've simplified the query here to boil it down to the basic issue, our actual method takes other parameters like page number, page size and sometimes query hints.  We also have to account for search fields being passed in and set as parameters on the Query instance.

I'd like to write a sister method to the one above that returns the result count of the same given jpqlQuery that the executeQuery method uses.  Inside the method I have no knowledge of what entities are involved in the query.

I have a working version of this that involves unwrap()ing the Query, retrieving the underlying SQL and wrapping that in a count query, but doing it this way requires a session and thus requires a transaction, which I'm trying to get away from.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should take a look at AbstractDAO pattern - http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/09/jpa-implementation-patterns-data-access-objects/ it would allow you to make methods such as `countAll` without unnecessary string manipulation

Comment: If I'm going to re-write the entire way I allow users to do entity searches, all keep that in mind.  But does anyone have any inpuut given the restrictions I listed above?

Comment: Criteria API makes this sort of thing super easy.